# I am working on project in mern stack where I want to implement multi-source multi-destination payment but I can find multi-source single destination

Tags: payment-gateway, mern, payment-processing

I have searched a lot like using razorpay , paypal , stripe etc but they provide solution for multi-source single destination and moreover I want the payment method to be as easy as possible so the user doesn't give on the application.

I looked up a lot of youtube videos but all are same multi-source to single destination only.